# registration form while filled and send, it should automatically save the filled field as pdf in server and send the link to "TO ADDRESS"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email, sendmail

I have created a big Registration form with many fields, if a end user comes and fill it and click "send" button, automatically a pdf file has to be created with same as in the "Registration from" and save in server , then the saved path has to be mailed to "TO ADDRESS".

I tried a lot on behalf of this functionalities, but i cant able to trigger out, Do anyone suggest me the best code for this.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the PDF part, you could use `dompdf` library that is there to make pdf files, you can use your form values and generate a pdf file and store that to your server.

And for attachment in mail, you can try this link, `http://www.sanwebe.com/2011/01/send-php-mail-with-attachment`, this one is great tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, will make a try of it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a html for Registration. Save data in databse or create file on the basis of user input then write a html file dynamically & using tcpdf convert it into pdf & send email as attachment. http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

There are also multiple php libraries to convert html to pdf